# vector art looks blurry when converted to HTML5 with google Swiffy

Tags: html, google-swiffy

I have used google Swiffy to convert quite a few swf files to HTML5 and have found that vector art (usually logos and buttons) often appears a little blurry once converted.

Is this a common issue? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the object on stage have total px values - its initial size & position

Comment: Thank you! That worked. My vector image was being used at 100% of actual size, but within the movie clip the x and y values were not set to zero. I fixed that and converted the file again and the vector image is now crisp.

Comment: By "total px values" do you mean rounded e.g. non-decimal? So instead of 99.9px it should be 100px?

I'm not sure I'm following - all my objects have px values but some of them are blurry and some of them arent. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the MovieClip should have selected and in Display select "Render:Cache as Bitmap" selected in Properties(F3)